Proper A/B test analysis with related segments
I have the data of an online A/B experiment (e.g. a redesign) and there's a concern about a different effect on different platform - web and mobile. The users was splitted by some identificator, and one user can be in both platform (same id).
user_id | platform | denom | num
--------------------------------
1       | web      | 1     | 0
1       | mobile   | 1     | 1
2       | web      | 0     | 0    
2       | mobile   | 1     | 1

I would like to test for significance change of conversion metrics:

denominator is a count of users in test (the whole or in one platform)
numerator is a count of users who did something (e.g. buy or pay)

I tested a stat sig of the whole test, and I've decided to segment users into two segments by platform and estimate if the effect of the treatment is different between the segments.  And there is the problem with simple adding segment as an another variable to regression.
[|Platform]=+⋅Platform+⋅+⋅Platform×

The logic is following: a positive change on one platform may induce user to visit another platform. So I can detect the difference in denominator in second platform between target and control groups, and if numerator stay the same this should lead me to the conclusion that conversion on second platform decrease, while I do a good change. And this aproach  is not good to evaluate the effect of an intervention on different platform, because I would like to see a positive change in metric in this case.
How can I analyze the whole experiments and the sub-segments by platform? Maybe I should use a cluster analysis with negative inter-class correlation? I would appreciate any tips.
